# Java : method that takes in argument any attribute of any class

Tags: java

I need to create a method that takes in argument **any attribute of any class**. But i dont want it to be of type String, to avoid refactoring problems while renaming an attribute and to get the errors in **Markers** Tab of eclipse, and not while running my application.

Having a class Person :

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    // other attributes...

    // getters and setters...

}
```

Now the needed method :

```
void getAnAttributeOfAClass( <which_type_or_class_here?> attr_as_arg){

   // Now I need to get the name of attribute that would be of class Strin...

}
```

Is there a function or a method, by which we can specify an attribute?

For example :

```
Person.class.name
```

Would it be of class **Property** ?

**EDIT**

More exactly (@Smallhacker answer helped me), I need to verify at compile time if the argument is really an attribute of the specified class.

```
Person.class.name // no compile time error
Person.class.nameXXX // compile time error
```

Comment: can you explain it a little more?

Comment: I've just done an edit. thanks

Answer (score 2):

The closest to what you want is Reflection API's `Field` or JavaBeans `Introspector` API's `PropertyDescriptor`.

But usually things like that are not needed in Java projects because there are libraries which handle these concerns.

You could pass a `Class` object along with a `String` name, then let your method use `Introspector` internally to read that property.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand you well, but there is a class java.lang.reflect.Field, that has a method getName() that would give your the name of the field.

In your example, to get field name, you would do: Person.class.getDeclaredField("name").

EDIT: to get the value of a field in an object, you would do: field.get(obj);

OK, let's say You have the following variables:

```
Person person = ...; // initialized with some Person
Field nameField = Person.class.getDeclaredField("name");
```

Now to get the name of person, you would do:

```
String personName = (String)nameField.get(person);
```

Actually, this would throw an exception because name is a private field. You can however bypass the protection by doing:

```
nameField.setAccessible(true);
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the edit of your answer, but can you do another edit, because I didn't understand exactly what you mean. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Java lacks an ability to reference member variables in a way that can be analyzed at compile time.

There may be some kind of library to simplify this somewhat, but it wouldn't provide a full solution due to limitations in the language itself.

Comment: Is the errors at the compile time, the ones shown in the "Markers" tab without running the application? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe java generics can help you with this.

You can do something like:

```
class YourClass<E> {
    void getAnAttributeOfAClass(E attr_as_arg){

        // some code

    }        
}

someVariable = new YourClass<Person>();

someVariable.getAnAtributeOfAClass(someObject); //this will not compile if someObject is not an instance of Person
```

But I still don't know what you want to do exactly inside the method.